# Law of total expectation for larger conditioning sets.

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Does the law of total expectation hold for more than one conditioning variables, i.e. $E[E[X|Y, Z]]= E[X]?$
It is easy to show it for discrete Y, Z, but does it hold for continuous conditioning sets as well?

Answer (score 1):

It holds for any number of variables. More generally, $E(E(X|\mathcal G))=EX$ for any sigma algebra $\mathcal G$.